# Generator memory usage vs for loop memory usage

Tags: python, memory

I've been learning a lot about python generators recently, and I have a question about their memory usage.

Here are two ways to do the same thing:

First with a generator

```py
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob

csvlist = glob("/path/to/my/data/*.csv")
df_gen = (pd.read_csv(file) for file in csvlist)

for df in df_gen:
    # do your processing here
    process_data(df)
```

And now without

```py
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob

csvlist = glob("/path/to/my/data/*.csv")

for csv in csvlist:
    df = pd.read_csv(csv)
    # do your processing here
    process_data(df)
```

I understand that the generator way will load each dataframes into memory, one at a time. However, is this any more memory efficient than the second way where I simply read in the data from each CSV inside the loop?

Comment: Nitpick: `filelist` -> `csvlist`.

Comment: Thanks Austin, fixed

Comment: I think they will use the same amount of memory, as in both examples you are reading each file one at a time. You can view the memory usage of each script by profiling using a tool like this https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/